# .htaccess Do not Redirect Specific Words

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I wanted to redirect

- domain.com/blabla to domain.com/index.php?q=blabla
- domain.com/blabla/2 to domain.com/index.php?q=blabla&p=2

I used this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,NC]
```

Bu I need to DO NOT REDIRECT some words. For example:

Redirecting domain.com/user to domain.com/index.php?q=user is OK

But it's redirecting domain.com/admin to domain.com/admin/?q=admin

I don't want this to happen. BTW there is a folder named "admin". The "specific words" I'm talking about are folders. But please consider that these words should not have to be folders (if there's any change on htaccess, I don't know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an exclusion rule before these rules:

```
# ignore these URIs
RewriteRule ^(admin|something)(/|$) - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: 1st, why did you changed them to QSA? 2nd, I don't know what's going on but it only works for second word. That make no sense. I'm at local with wamp btw.

Comment: `NC` was not needed because you already had `A-Za-z` in your regex. `QSA` is for preserving original query string. For which URL it didn't work?

Comment: (based on your code) domain.com/admin still redirects. domain.com/something is not. I don't know it must be something about server or browser cache etc. I'll try again after restarting.

Comment: no. that was not even a real folder. it was just an example. I've restarted wamp, tried from another browser. problem solved. must be about caching right?

Comment: Yes these URLs are cached in browser also

Comment: Yes I rolled back my changes.